# Undefined reference with my own iteration methods

Tags: c++

I declared and implemented some iteration methods for my `String` class: `begin()`, `end()`, etc... but when I try to use them in a test program I get undefined reference for all of them.

`String.h`:

```
public:

typedef char* iterator;
typedef const char* const_iterator;
typedef std::reverse_iterator<iterator> reverse_iterator;
typedef std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator> const_reverse_iterator;

iterator begin();
iterator begin() const;
iterator end();
iterator end() const;
const_iterator cbegin();
const_iterator cend();
reverse_iterator rbegin();
reverse_iterator rbegin() const;
reverse_iterator rend();
reverse_iterator rend() const;
const_reverse_iterator crbegin();
const_reverse_iterator crend();

private:
    char* string_;
```

`String.cpp`:

```
inline String::iterator String::begin() {
    return string_;
}

inline String::iterator String::begin() const {
    return string_;
}

inline String::iterator String::end() {
    return string_ + length_ - 1;
}

inline String::iterator String::end() const {
    return string_ + length_ - 1;
}

inline String::const_iterator String::cbegin() {
    return string_;
}

inline String::const_iterator String::cend() {
    return string_ + length_ - 1;
}

inline String::reverse_iterator String::rbegin() {
    return reverse_iterator(end()); 
}

inline String::reverse_iterator String::rbegin() const { 
    return reverse_iterator(end()); 
}

inline String::reverse_iterator String::rend() {
    return reverse_iterator(begin());
}

inline String::reverse_iterator String::rend() const {
    return reverse_iterator(begin());
}

inline String::const_reverse_iterator String::crbegin() {
    return reverse_iterator(end());
}

inline String::const_reverse_iterator String::crend() {
    return reverse_iterator(begin());
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Silly question: Where exactly are you allocating `string_`?

Comment: Putting inline on a function definition, when it is declared elsewhere, is a pretty bad idea.

Comment: inlining in a .cpp file is somewhat worthless. move the entire brunt of your .cpp to your .h, keeping the inline keyword, or remove it in the cpp file. either/or, but not both, and (as you've seen) not either.

Comment: Marking the function as `inline` prevents them from having external linkage, which means that they cannot be used from another translation unit.

Answer (score 0):

Undefined reference? But it compiles fine.
I added one constructor:

```
String(const char *cc) {
    string_ = new char[length_ = strlen(cc) + 1];
    strcpy(string_, cc);
}
```

Of course, added a data member as

```
int _length;
```

And my test program as below:

String aa("abc");
String::iterator itr = aa.begin();
cout << itr << endl;

prints "abc"
No problem!

Comment: My constructor is like that. I remove the `inline` tags and it works. Who knows why.